# Excel: how to align matching values between two columns and space out the differences

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, alignment

I have two columns of data that overlap, looking something like this:

```
-------------------------
| Aardvarks  | Bears    |
| Bears      | Dogs     |
| Cats       | Giraffes |
| Giraffes   | Hippos   |
| Monkeys    | Rhinos   |
| Rhinos     | Zebras   |
-------------------------
```

Is there any way to align matching values between the two columns, whilst adding blank cells where differences exist, so that I get an end result like this:

```
-------------------------
| Aardvarks |           |
| Bears     | Bears     |
| Cats      |           |
|           | Dogs      |
| Giraffes  | Giraffes  |
|           | Hippos    |
| Monkeys   |           |
| Rhinos    | Rhinos    |
|           | Zebras    |
-------------------------
```

I've seen people ask similar questions on here, but all rely on the Column `A` having some sort of "complete" data and and Column B having incomplete data that needs sorting.

My issue is that both columns have duplicate and unique data (in the above example, Column `A` doesn't have all the animals).

Is there some way to align and arrange the columns to get this end result I'm looking for?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can we assume that both lists have the common words in the same sequence?  Can we also assume that the number of needed blank lines isn't necessarily one?

Comment: You could probably do this with formulas, but the logical solution would be VBA.

Comment: @fixer1234, yes to both questions.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to waste people's time, but after doing even more online searching I found a solution to my own problem.

I found this site below that offers a VBA solution to the problem I was facing. The script worked perfectly for what I was hoping to achieve.

http://sites.madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/text-functions/line-up-matches

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

The website looks to be down... thankfully I saved the useful VB last year

```
Option Explicit

Sub LineEmUp()
'Author:    Jerry Beaucaire
'Date:      7/5/2010
'Summary:   Line up a random number of columns so all matching
'           items are on the same rows
Dim LC  As Long
Dim Col As Long
Dim LR  As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Spot last column of data
    LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Add new key column  to collect unique values
    Cells(1, LC + 1) = "Key"
    For Col = 1 To LC
        Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(Rows.Count, Col)).SpecialCells(xlConstants).Copy _
           Cells(Rows.Count, LC + 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Next Col

    Columns(LC + 1).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Cells(1, LC + 2), Unique:=True
    Columns(LC + 2).Sort Key1:=Cells(2, LC + 2), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'Fill in new table headers w/formatting
    Range("A1", Cells(1, LC)).Copy Cells(1, LC + 3)

'Fill in new table values
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, LC + 2).End(xlUp).Row
    With Range(Cells(2, LC + 3), Cells(LR, LC + 2 + LC))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC" & LC + 2 & ",C[-" & LC + 2 _
                        & "],0)), RC" & LC + 2 & ", """")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

'Cleanup/Erase old values
    Range("A1", Cells(1, LC + 2)).EntireColumn.Delete xlShiftToLeft
    Columns.Autofit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```